# Solve the problem $U_{xx} + U_{yy}= 0$ in upper half plane with the boundary condition U(x,0)= g(x) where g is 0 for x>0 and 1 for x<1.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I went through this problem in a complex analysis course. I read that we can translate this region into the unit disk by a conformal map T(z)from the upper half-plane to the unit disc.

Then the solution will be [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GP0d.png][1]][1]

I know that we have to use the transformation $T(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$. Can someone tell me ho the integral will look after substitution?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GP0d.png

Comment: This is easier to solve in the upper halfplane. *Hint:* $\arg z$ is harmonic as the imaginary part of the complex logarithm.

Comment: You can find the Poisson integral formula for the upper halfplane here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-plane.